# Returning a Promise from a Directive Using an Attribute

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I want to place a promise attribute in a directive that opens up a modal form.

As you know, the promise attribute has a "please wait" spinner until the httpost call is returned.

### markup

```
cg-busy="{promise:downloadCtrl.promise}
```

### js

```
viewModel.promise = $http.post(ajaxUrl, { searchCriteria: searchValues })
```

I entered the following on my modal form:

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" cg-busy="{promise:downloadCtrl.promise}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            file-download
            download-type={{downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadType}}
            download-id={{downloadCtrl.attributes.downloadId}}>
        Download files
    </button>
</div>
```

I entered the following in the associated directive:

```
.directive('fileDownload', ['$http', '$parse', function ($http, $parse)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller)
        {
            //for testing purpose. need to be removed.
            console.log('download type on file download directive: ' + attrs.downloadType)
            console.log('download id on file download directive: ' + attrs.downloadId)

            element.bind('click', function ()
            {
                ajaxUrl = root + 'FileUpload/download?' +
                          'ExternalDocumentID=' + attrs.downloadType +
                          '&' + 'FileID=' + attrs.downloadId;
                viewModel.promise = $http.post(ajaxUrl, {
                    headers: { "Content-Type": undefined }
                })
                .success(function (status)
                {
                    if (status.Succeed)
                    {
                        alert('Files Downloaded successfully.');
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        alert(status.Err);
                    }
                });
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

I got the error message "viewmodel is not defined" which makes sense. However, I don't know how to do it inside the directive.

Can someone please inform me how I can accomplish this?

Comment: The error says it all.  You need to replace viewModel in your directive with scope... and `cg-busy="{promise:promise}"`

Comment: Thanks, that worked great :)

Answer (score 0):

### Creating and Invoking Expression Attributes on Directives

Add an expression attribute to your HTML

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group" cg-busy="{promise:downloadCtrl.promise}">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default"
            file-download
            download-on-click="downloadCtrl.promise = $promise"
            download-url={{downloadCtrl.attributes.url}}>
        Download files
    </button>
</div>
```

Use the `$parse` service to parse the expression. Then on each click, save the promise locally, and invoke the expression with the promise as a local.

```
.directive('fileDownload', ['$http', '$parse', function ($http, $parse)
{
    return {
        restrict: 'A',

        link: function (scope, element, attrs, controller)
        {
            //Parse download-on-click attribute
            var downloadOnClickFn = $parse(attrs.downloadOnClick);                
            element.on('click', function ()
            {
                var ajaxUrl = attrs.downloadUrl;
                //save promise
                var promise = $http.post(ajaxUrl, {
                    headers: { "Content-Type": undefined }
                })
                .then (function onFullfilled(response)
                {
                    console.log("Http post status = ", response.status); 
                    //return response for chaining
                    return response;
                });
                //Invoke expression
                downloadOnClickFn(scope, {$promise:promise});
                scope.$apply();
            });
        }
    };
}])
```

The `downloadOnClickFn` function uses two arguments: `context` and `locals`. Set the context to the scope and set the locals to `{$promise: promise}`. This executes the attribute expression in the context of the scope and exposes the local promise as `$promise`.

Common convention is to expose local directive variables with `$` as a prefix to differentiate them from scope varables.

For more information on `$parse`, see [AngularJS $parse Service API Reference](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$parse).

> ### Deprecation Notice
>
> The `$http` legacy promise methods `.success` and `.error` have been deprecated. Use the standard `.then` method instead.<sup>[1](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/service/$http#deprecation-notice)</sup>

Comment: I have placed your code in my directive, but on the last line, I'm getting the following error: Object doesn't support property or method 'assign' for the line: downloadOnClickFn.assign(scope.$parent, { $promise: promise });

Comment: Check my update. Since the directive has no scope, $parent was not necesssary. The `assign` function was not necessary and I added `$apply()`.